# What's the relationship between didReceiveMemoryWarning and dealloc?

Tags: ios, dealloc, didreceivememorywarning

Will `dealloc` be called when under memory pressure? If it's true, is it called before `didReceiveMemoryWarning` or after? Also, when the view controller is being released, is it for sure that `dealloc` will be called?

Comment: By the way, the simulator let's you also simulate a memory warning event, so you can see exactly what it does. Just put NSLog statements or the like in your various view controller methods (e.g. viewDidLoad, viewDidUnload, dealloc, didReceiveMemoryWarning, etc.), and you'll see precisely what it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is simply informing you that you are low in memory. Neither the view nor the controller is released. On the other hand, prior to iOS 6, you might received `viewDidUnload` at the same time, which is informing you that the view has been removed (but not the view controller). That's why you override `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, so you can also free up any other stuff that your view controller can safely release. But these low memory situations, the view controller is never released. Worst case scenario, if `viewDidUnload` was called, the view will be released, but not the controller.

FYI, I quote from the documentation:

> Memory is a critical resource in iOS, and view controllers provide
>   built-in support for reducing their memory footprint at critical
>   times. The `UIViewController` class provides some automatic handling of
>   low-memory conditions through its `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method,
>   which releases unneeded memory.
>
> When a low-memory warning occurs, the `UIViewController` class purges
>   its views if it knows it can reload or recreate them again later. If
>   this happens, [if running iOS versions prior to 6.0] it also calls the `viewWillUnload` and `viewDidUnload`
>   methods to give your code a chance to relinquish ownership of any
>   objects that are associated with your view hierarchy, including
>   objects loaded from the nib file, objects created in your `viewDidLoad`
>   method, and objects created lazily at runtime and added to the view
>   hierarchy.

and

> [`didReceiveMemoryWarning`] is called when the system determines that the amount of
>   available memory is low. The default implementation of this method
>   attempts to release the view controller’s view [in iOS versions prior to 6.0]. To be released, the
>   view must not have a superview; that is, it is not part of a view
>   hierarchy. For more information on how views are unloaded, see [“The
>   View Controller Life Cycle”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10).
>
> You can override this method to release any additional memory used by
>   your view controller. If you do, your implementation of this method
>   must call the super implementation at some point to allow the view
>   controller to release its view. If your view controller holds
>   references to views in the view hierarchy, you should release those
>   references in the `viewDidUnload` method instead.

**Update:**

In answer to your other question (which you may not care about now that you realize that view controllers are not, themselves, released when the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is invoked), yes, when the item is finally released (and has a retain count of zero, i.e. the alloc and all of the various retains are now offset by corresponding release statements), then `dealloc` will be invoked.

Answer (score 3):

There is no relationship, didReceiveMemoryWarning is giving you the chance to react to the low memory situation by deleting any un-needed resources.

If a view controller, or any other object, is released and its retain count decreases to 0 then it will be deleted and its dealloc will be called.

If an object is released but its retain count does not reduce to 0 then it won't be deleted thus its dealloc won't get called.

A dealloc is called when an object is being deleted, deletion and release are not the same thing. An object is deleted when its retain count reaches 0.